# Calling WCF SOAP Service with Workflow Manager 1.0 .NET Send Activity

Tags: wcf, soap, workflow, .net-4.5, workflow-manager-1.x

Workflow Manager 1.0 documentation - [Outbound Messaging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj193480(v=azure.10).aspx) - states:

> The .NET 4 Framework Send & ReceiveReply activities can be used for SOAP-based messaging, although custom code is required.

When I create a workflow that uses the Send Activity and try to publish it to Workflow Manager 1.0 server (Windows Server 2012-R2 with Workflow Manager 1.0 installed and functional) I get the following error:

> Workflow XAML failed validation due to the following errors: 
>   Invalid type(s) 'System.ServiceModel.Activities.Send'. 
>   Invalid type(s) 'System.ServiceModel.Endpoint'. 
>   Invalid type(s) 'System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding'. 
>   Invalid type(s) 'System.ServiceModel.Activities.SendParametersContent'.

Has anyone successfully used the [Send Activity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.workflow.activities.sendactivity(v=vs.110).aspx) in custom code with Workflow Manager 1.0 to Send WCF SOAP messages?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the HttpSend as explained in the [Getting Started Tutorial for Workflow Manager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn217859(v=azure.10).aspx).
We have used HttpSend successfully. Only found that it's not handling the Cookie HTTPRequestHeader.